# Database/Cache in Azure Service Bus for jobs in queue completed elsewhere

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I've an API (python-flask app) running on an app service in azure and want to implement a queuing system using Azure Service Bus such that requests from API are sent to a simple FIFO queue managed/ran by the service bus. Another resource in Azure will be pulling from this queue and running the jobs based on the contents of the json/payload contained in the message in the queue element.

When this element has been processed by the other resource I want to encode the job status/metadata (e.g., "finished" along with metadata such as the location where resulting data was stored). I read about such a system that makes use of the lightweight database offered by Redis, however, I'm wondering if something like this lightweight database/cache system of job status/ids/metadata is available through Azure Service Bus? I'm aware that Redis can be run standalone on a VM in Azure, however, if this can all be managed via the service bus that would be ideal. I couldn't find specifics on this being offered within Azure Service Bus and due to how this job metadata is later being accessed I cannot just push metadata messages to a new queue.

Does anyone have any insight on this or potential alternatives? If Redis can be run alongside flask within the same App Service then that would be ideal, but again I wasn't able to find anything explicit on this and it doesn't seem possible to simultaneously run a flask server/app and Redis server at the same time on an App Service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if something like this lightweight database/cache system
> of job status/ids/metadata is available through Azure Service Bus?

Azure Service Bus is a fully managed enterprise message broker, Azure Redis is a NoSQL database with steroids. It also offers queue mechanism and some other data structures.

> it doesn't seem possible to simultaneously run a flask server/app and
> Redis server at the same time on an App Service.

You can, but inside containers.

Please check if this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39008342/1384539